# Module not found, problem can not resolve style-loader

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, sass

I am getting this error
ERROR in ./src/client/index.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'style-loader'
This is my index.js even though I have specified the path correctly

```
import { checkForName } from './js/nameChecker'
import { handleSubmit } from './js/formHandler'


import './styles/base.scss'
import './styles/footer.scss'
import './styles/form.scss'
import './styles/header.scss'
import './styles/resets.scss'

console.log(checkForName);

alert("I EXIST")
console.log("CHANGE!!");
```

And this is my config file, I have tried npm install style-loader css-loader --save but still isn't working

```
const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin")
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/client/index.js',
    mode: 'development',
    devtool: 'source-map',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: '/\.js$/',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: "babel-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader' ]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
            template: "./src/client/views/index.html",
            filename: "./index.html",
        }),
        new CleanWebpackPlugin({
            // Simulate the removal of files
            dry: true,
            // Write Logs to Console
            verbose: true,
            // Automatically remove all unused webpack assets on rebuild
            cleanStaleWebpackAssets: true,
            protectWebpackAssets: false
        })
    ]
}
```

this is JSON code

```
{
  "name": "example-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node src/server/index.js",
    "build-prod": "webpack --config webpack.prod.js",
    "build-dev": "webpack  --config webpack.dev.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "webpack": "^4.35.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.10.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.10.2",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^3.6.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "sass-loader": "^7.3.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.7.2"
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Judging from the code, you pasted it looks correct. Could you perhaps paste your package.json as well?

Comment: i just added the JSON code above, make it easier to read, thank you

Comment: I had a problem running npm run build-dev commend on node.js v18 before wasn't working I had to install node v16 in order to make it work then it worked. perhaps could be a problem for the node version that I am working with?

Comment: Might be, I know there are some issues with node-sass (which I think sass-loader uses) and certain node versions. I will look into this and get back to you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used your configurations and managed to build after updating the versions of node-sass and sass-loader. Could you try these versions (update in your `package.json` and run `npm install`)

```
    "node-sass": "^7.0.3",
    "sass-loader": "10.3.1",
```

Comment: worked properly as expected!! Thank you a lot :).